# How custom a form with twig

Tags: theming, forms, 8

I make a form programmatically, and I am looking how a web designer can change render.

```
 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{

    $form['metier'] = array(
        '#type' => 'search',
        '#title' => $this->t('Métier'),
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#placeholder'=>'Rechercher une personne par son métier',
        '#attributes' => array('title' => $this->t('Rechercher une personne par son métier')),
    );

    $form['position'] = array(
        '#type' => 'search',
        '#title' => $this->t('Où'),
        '#placeholder'=>'Où',
        '#attributes' => array('title' => $this->t('Où')),
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Search'),
    );

    return $form;

}
```

If the path of my form is `/test` the suggestion template `form--test.html.twig` doens't work.

I would like give access to a template for webdesigner can custom the render.

I can do something like that :

```
  $form['metier'] = array(
        '#type' => 'search',
        '#title' => $this->t('Métier'),
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#placeholder'=>'Rechercher une personne par son métier',
        '#attributes' => array('title' => $this->t('Rechercher une personne par son métier')),
        '#prefix'=>'<div class="form-group">',
        '#suffix'=>'</div>'
    );
```

But it's hard coded.

So I am looking for a way to return a `brut` table and let the web designer make his template.

The best way for the designer ll be :

**form--test.html.twig**

```
<div class="col-md-12">{{ form.metier }}</div>
<div class="col-md-12">{{ form.position }}</div>
<div class="col-md-12">{{ form.submit }}</div>
```

I don't know if I am right, I have try to return my variable $form to a template like that :

```
return array(
    '#theme' => 'form_test',
    '#form' => $form,
  );
```

All work I can access to my fields with

> {{ form.metier }}
>   {{ form.position }}
>   {{ form.submit }}

But the submit button doesn't work because the hidden fields are not display like the `form_token` and he is not in my variable $form.

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement hook_theme() in your .module file to define a new theme implementation, set the #theme key in your form to the name of your implementation and create a twig template with this same name, but replacing hyphens with underscores:

**example.module**

```
function example_theme() {
  return [
    'my_awesome_form' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
    ],
  ];
```

**Form/MyAwesomeForm.php**

```
class MyAwesomeForm extends FormBase {
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['#theme'] = 'my_awesome_form';
    [...]
```

**templates/my-awesome-form.html.twig**

```
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ form.form_build_id }}
  {{ form.form_token }}
  {{ form.form_id }}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      {{ form.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      {{ form.type }}
    </div>
  </div>
  [...]
```

In this example `form.name` and `form.type` are your form fields, the array keys that you used to create the form, and I used bootstrap markup to show them in two columns.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

PS: This is a copy of my post at https://www.drupal.org/node/2788835#comment-11785706. I cloned it here because I'm not allowed to post comments.

Comment: This is exactly how it should be done

Answer (score 1):

you can access your filed with this code this is perfectly works

```
{{ form.metier }} {{ form.position }} {{ form.submit }}
{# Renders the rest of the form #}
{{ form|without('metier','position','submit') }}
```

Comment: i ll try that and let you know thx

Comment: ok welcome..but tell me must.how many face this problem.

Comment: Its my problem too . {{ form|without('metier','position','submit') }} worked but when we have a lot fields how to use this ? This code was very big and not good . {{ form.actions.submit }} was show element but I want after submit form , page redirect . How to use this ?

Comment: it is not possible to display without twig filter.you can get more information from here **https://www.drupal.org/node/2212845**  and if you will find a solution tell me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
{{ form.form_build_id }}
{{ form.form_id }}
```

These are the fields that make the submit work.

Comment: nop that don't work, {{ form.form_build_id }} and {{ form.form_id }} doesn't exist in the form variable

Comment: I found those fields by debugging with `{{ dump() }}`. The one thing i did different is not to add the #form in the array but made the theme like this; `$themes['form_test'] = [
      'render element' => 'form',
    ];`

Comment: i don't have this field in {{ dump() }} how do you pass your form to your theme ?

Comment: `dump()` is only available when you change the twig.config debug setting in the /sites/default/services.yml file

Comment: yes i got it, but i see just field in my '#form' variable, i see nothing like build_id or form_build_id

Comment: What is in your theme?

Comment: for the moment that : `<pre>
{{ dump() }}
</pre>


{{ form.metier}}

{{ form.position}}

{{ form.submit}}
` but this is how i call my theme from my form : `return array(
          '#theme' => 'recherche_form',
          '#form' => $form,
        );`